# How do I prove 'S x > 0' from scratch in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

How do I prove the simple fact

```
forall x:nat, S x > 0.
```

?

My logic is that

1. For any nat n, either n > 0 or  n = 0.
2. S x = 0 leads to a contradiction.

My main problem is that I can't memorize all these trivial theorems/lemma about nat, and I don't know the Search commands well enough.

I've tried to 'destruct gt' or the '>' constructor, or do some inversion on 'gt'. But I couldn't figure out the syntax or whether this is even the right direction.

Any help (except heavy things like omega) is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you stick to standard Coq, your lemma is indeed the same than proving `0 <= n`. You prove this by direct induction on n, or, as other have said, using some library lemma. (`apply le_n_S; exact (le_0_n _)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach (based on your observation about the natural numbers).

First of all, we need to import a module which contains many facts about natural numbers (without this import `Search` won't find what we are going to look for):

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.
```

Now, let's look for the lemma, which states that any `nat` is either `0` or greater than `0`:

```
Search ({_ = 0} + {_}).
```

This search results in

```
zerop: forall n : nat, {n = 0} + {0 < n},
```

which is Coq's parlance for the previously observed fact.

Using that `zerop` lemma we can finally prove our goal:

```
Goal forall x:nat, S x > 0.
  intros x. 
  destruct (zerop (S x)).

(* subcase S x = 0 *)
  discriminate.             (* deals with the contradiction *)

(* subcase S x > 0 *)
  assumption.
Qed.
```

---

By the way, there is a lemma in the standard library (as of Coq v8.5), which states exactly the same thing, as your lemma:

```
Search (S _ > 0).
```

This results in `gt_Sn_O: forall n : nat, S n > 0`, and you can just look at the implementation of this lemma in the standard library (which in its turn uses a couple of lemmas).

Answer (score 2):

Here a few commands that may help you:

- `Unset Printing Notations.` in order to be able to see what symbols correspond to
- `Print ID.` to see what the identifier `ID` is
- `unfold ID.` to replace `ID` by its definition
- `SearchAbout (ID (CON ?m) ?n)` to look for results involving `ID` apply to `CON` of a subterm and any other subterm (if you reuse the same `?m` placeholder, the search will only return results where the corresponding subterms match).

In your case for instance, this could lead to this interactive session:

```
Unset Printing Notations.
Goal forall x:nat, S x > 0.
intro x.
Print gt.
unfold gt.
Print lt.
unfold lt.
Print le.
SearchAbout (le (S ?m) (S ?n)).
apply le_n_S.
SearchAbout (le 0 ?m).
apply le_0_n.
Qed.
```

Comment: For completeness' sake: `SearchAbout` is deprecated in Coq 8.5. The [manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual008.html) suggests using `Search` (it behaves the same way as `SearchAbout` in Coq 8.4).

Comment: Thanks! I'm running `8.5beta2` but never got any warning and get back the right answer so I assumed it was still valid. I'll try to keep it in mind (I don't use Coq that much anymore.)

Comment: [company-coq](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/company-coq) gives a warning (if you are a ProofGeneral user).

Answer (score 1):

I propose an alternative solution based on a computational encoding of the `<` operator:

```
From mathcomp
Require Import ssreflect ssrbool ssrfun eqtype ssrnat.

Lemma test n : 0 < n.+1.
Proof. by []. Qed.
```

How does this work? Indeed, this works because we define the `<` operation as a function:

```
(m < n) = (m.+1 <= n) = (m.+1 - n == 0)
```

when applied to your lemma, it becomes:

```
(0 < n.+1) = (0.+1 <= n.+1) = (1 - n.+1 == 0) = (0 - n == 0) = (0 == 0) = true
```